# symfony/propel: problem trying to add a new object action in a backend module

Tags: symfony1

i have created this model:

```
propel:
  shop_orders:
    orders_id: { phpName: Id, type: INTEGER, size: '11', primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, required: true }
    email: { type: VARCHAR, size: '45', required: true }
```

Then i have generated an admin module and i have add this below to generator.yml:

```
config:
  actions: ~
  fields:  ~
  list:
    object_actions:
      foo: {}
```

When I click on the foo action It generates this url:

> backend_dev.php/sp1/ListFoo/action?id=1

and I get this message:

> Action "sp1/action" does not exist.

sf 1.4/propel

Any idea?

Javier

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same problem with propel 1.5. Tried fixing it by adding routing rules, etc. But what has seemed to work has been simply adding single quotes around the action name in the generator.yml:

list:
    object_actions:
      foo:
        module: foo
        action: 'Action'

Answer (score 0):

before my answer i got a couple questions myself. What where you trying to do with this:

```
config:
  actions: ~
  fields:  ~
  list:
    object_actions:
      foo: {}
```

I think there should be something like:

```
config:
  actions: ~
  fields:  ~
  list:
    object_actions:
      foo:
        module: foo
        action: action_name
```

Now, back to your question, the generated link results from a partial located in the generator theme. You can find it at:
 `generator > sfPropelGenerator > theme_name > template > templates > _list_actions.php`

there you can find code that looks like:

```
[....]
<li class="sf_admin_action_<?php echo $params['class_suffix'] ?>">
  <?php echo $this->addCredentialCondition($this->getLinkToAction($name, $params, false), $params)."\n" ?>
</li>
[....]
```

My guess is that when you defined the new object_action the getLinkToAction received some default values at $params.

Try modifying your generator.yml, clearing cache and check it again.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Peace i have resolve this bug by downloading stable version of symfony and regenerating a new backend at the moment you can do "copy/paste" to upgrade you backend by the old backend 
Good Luck